# How can i draw a curve like one shown below in latex?

Tags: graphics, histogram

[image]

How can i draw a curve like one shown below in latex?

Comment: Do you have any data or an equation for your curve?

Comment: No actually the curve is random and used for explaining some concepts

Answer (score 3):

Here is a random solution (each compilation gives a different curve):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\pgfmathsetseed{\pdfuniformdeviate 1000000}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % lab style
  \tikzset{lab/.style={text=black}}
  % draw axis
  \draw[gray!50] (0,0) node[below,lab]{$0$}
  -- (11,0) node[below,lab]{$L-1$} node[above,lab]{Intensity}
  (0,0) -- (0,5) node[above,lab]{Number of pixels};

  % random Tc and Xa
  \coordinate (Tc) at (0,rnd+2);
  \coordinate (Xa) at (rnd*4+3,0);

  % draw lines
  \draw (Tc) -- (Tc -| 10,0) node[above]{$T_c$};
  \draw[dashed] (Xa) node[below]{$X_a$} node[above left]{Under Exposed}
  node[above right]{Over Exposed} -- (Xa |- 0,5);

  % random curve
  \draw[rounded corners=5mm,thick]
  (0,0) \foreach \p in {1,...,9}{ -- (\p, rnd*4+.5) } -- (10,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at pgfplots. The [manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf) is really good with a lot of examples.
If you want a more specific answer you have to provide the data and a mwe.

Comment: It shoukd be rather comment, not answer.